# Plotly in Expected Flask Window

Tags: python, flask, plotly

I've cobbled together a very minimal flask app example for replication of my issue. The code below generates a simple plot which I want to be displayed within the out.html file. However, running the app, a plot is created but displayed in a windows of its own.

How can I force that plot to be rendered within the out.html file in approximately the location I want? Below is the minimal flask app and a minimal html file with some jinga2.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session
from flask_session import Session
import plotly.express as px

server = Flask(__name__)

@server.route('/')
def visual():
    df = px.data.gapminder().query("country=='Canada'")
    fig = px.line(df, x="year", y="lifeExp", title='Life expectancy in Canada')
    return  render_template('out.html', out = fig.show())     

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server.run(debug=True)
```

Contents of out.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1> 
    I want the figure to be about here
    </h1>
    {{out}}
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am also using plotly.express and waiting for some tips on how to make it open within the html page , will be playing around with it for the better part of the day and will update if i find anything

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `out = fig.show()`, use `out = fig.to_html(full_html=False)`

Then in your HTML file, instead of `{{ out }}`, use `{{ out|safe }}`

For more information: https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.io.to_html.html